# C#.NET 4: How to open a form from inside a class file?

Tags: c#, .net

**NOTE: I searched and searched for this but I could not find the exact thing I was looking for...**

So, I'm making a game that's kinda like Fallout but uses a form GUI instead of an actual first-person game environment. I need the program to load a class file before anything else, and I want that class file to open the main menu. How could I get `Main.cs` (the class file to load first) to open `MainMenu.cs` (the form to open)?

This is what I attempted to do last:

```
Form MainMenu = new MainMenu();
MainMenu.Show();
```

Doing this brought up these errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Form' could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>       'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Show(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Don't make the variable name and the type name the same. `Form myMainMenu = new MainMenu(); myMainMenu.Show();`

Comment: I think you mean `MainMenu form = new MainMenu();` and as others have said, reference `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. Now to continue working on the game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error refers to this line:

```
Form MainMenu = new MainMenu();
```

That code doesn't know what `Form` is.  Unless it's in the same namespace (which it really shouldn't be in this case) then you need to either fully qualify it:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form mainMenu = new MainMenu();
```

or add a `using` directive to the file:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

As an additional step, if you haven't already done so, your class library will need an assembly reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.  (Note that this tightly couples your class library to Windows Forms as a technology.  So you won't be able to re-use the code without carrying a reference to Windows Forms.)

If the project itself is fully aware of the types and you're simply missing the `using` directive, you might more simply use the specific type, even just implicitly:

```
var mainMenu = new MainMenu();
```

(Note also how I changed the variable name slightly in some of this code, which leads me to...)

---

The second error refers to this line:

```
MainMenu.Show();
```

`MainMenu` is a *type*.  And `Show` is an *instance method* on an object of said type.  This line makes it look like you're calling it as a static method or trying to use `Show` as a type itself.  This is confusing the compiler.

In short, don't give your variables the same exact names as your types.  Instead:

```
Form mainMenu = new MainMenu();
mainMenu.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems, but the breaker is naming an object the same as its class (MainMenu = new MainMenu()).  This is confusing the compiler and causing the other errors.  The code should read

```
MainMenu myMainMenu = new MainMenu();
myMainMenu.Show();
```